# Selecting date range within 65 years using JOIN perhaps?

Tags: php, sql, date

am attempting to pull a query on a PHP posting script that will pull information

```
SELECT  `id`
FROM    `leads`
WHERE   `status` = 'Passed'
  AND   `campaign_id` = '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f046bd1d8ee'
```

original line is

```
$id_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `id` FROM  `leads` WHERE  `status` =  'Passed' AND     'campaign_id' =  '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f046bd1d8ee'"); 
$id = mysql_fetch_row($id_query); 
echo $id[0];
```

as such I wanted to add a date variable that will select greater then 65 years:

```
BETWEEN (current_date - "DateField") > 365.0 * 65.0
```

but obviously this does not work.  I was looking into using JOIN and add

```
AND 'datesubmitted_c' BETWEEN Date_Add(curDate(), INTERVAL -65 YEARS) AND curDate()'
$id_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `id` FROM  `leads` WHERE  `status` =  'Passed' AND     'campaign_id' =  '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f046bd1d8ee' AND 'datesubmitted_c' BETWEEN Date_Add(curDate(), INTERVAL -65 YEARS) AND curDate()'");
```

Not exactly sure if using a join would be appropriate?

Comment: `mysql` i assume (given PHP?) You were vague and tagged `sql`, but no specific engine.

Comment: 65 years ago, or 65 years in the future?

Comment: curdate() suggests MySQL too.

Comment: Please note that the `BETWEEN` predicate requires _2_ operands (in case it wasn't obvious from the answers): `column BETWEEN :lowerValue AND :upperValue`.  Also, the statement is equivalent to `WHERE column >= :lowerValue AND column <= :upperValue` - that is, the upper bound is _inclusive_; often/usually (especially when dealing with dates), you want the upper bound to be _exclusive_ (`column < :upperValue`).

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you're looking for the [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) method so you can check between a range. Something like:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   _condition_1_
  AND   date_column BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 65 YEAR)
```

Which would check if the date column `date_column` has a date that falls between today's date and 65 years from now.

Comment: I am using this in a php script to create csv files auto from sql:
    `$id_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `id` FROM  `leads` WHERE  `status` =  'Passed' AND  `campaign_id` =  '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f046bd1d8ee' AND BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -65 YEAR)'");   
would I need to add a JOIN to this to make it work proper?

Comment: No, JOINs are only for referring to other tables, not adding conditions to a single table.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE
  "DateField" BETWEEN Date_Add(curDate(), INTERVAL -65 YEARS) AND curDate()
```