# Selecting data within PHP script between date ranges SQL

Tags: php, sql, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Selecting date range within 65 years using JOIN perhaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791626/selecting-date-range-within-65-years-using-join-perhaps)

I am attempting to pull a query on a PHP posting script that will pull information

```
SELECT  `id`
FROM    `leads`
WHERE   `status` = 'Passed'
  AND   `campaign_id` = '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f046bd1d8ee'
```

original line is

```
$id_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `id` FROM  `leads` WHERE  `status` =  'Passed' AND     'campaign_id' =  '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f046bd1d8ee'");<br>
$id = mysql_fetch_row($id_query);<br>
echo $id[0];
```

as such I wanted to add a date variable that will select greater then 65 years:

```
BETWEEN (current_date - "DateField") > 365.0 * 65.0
```

but obviously this does not work.  I was looking into using JOIN and add

```
AND 'datesubmitted_c' BETWEEN Date_Add(curDate(), INTERVAL -65 YEARS) AND curDate()
```

So my new line looks like this

```
$id_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `id` FROM  `leads` WHERE  `status` =  'Passed' AND
campaign_id' =  '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f046bd1d8ee' AND 'datesubmitted_c' BETWEEN 
Date_Add(curDate(), INTERVAL -65 YEARS) AND curDate()'");
```

This does not seem to work properly still, any suggestions?

Comment: didn't you ask this question earlier today? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791626/selecting-date-range-within-65-years-using-join-perhaps

Comment: Use two statements: less than and greater than? Eg. `WHERE datesubmitted_c > '1992-09-07' AND datesubmitted_c < NOW()`

Comment: I did Mat I redid the post quite a few times so I just posted what I had uptodate and was working/wasnt working.  The last one seemed all over the place too =)

Comment: In that case, you should edit the original question rather than post a new one.

Comment: don't re-ask questions again, edit your original question.

Comment: Dully noted, I shall edit and clean up posts in the future =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$id_query  =  mysql_query("
    SELECT  `id` FROM  `leads` WHERE  `status` =  'Passed' AND
    `campaign_id` =  '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f046bd1d8ee' AND STR_TO_DATE(datesubmitted_c, '%m/%d/%y') >= Date_Add(curDate(), INTERVAL -65 YEARS) "
);
```

Since you just want date submitted in the last 65 years, you don't need the BETWEEN, and that syntax is less portable.

The datesubmitted_c field needs to be of type date.  To verify this, do a "DESC leads;"  If it isn't of the date type, you'll need to do a STR_TO_DATE(datesubmitted, '%m/%d/%y') AS date
 on the fly, or better yet, change the type of the field (if you can)

Comment: Still stating it is an invalid argument :\

Comment: am placing
    SELECT `id` FROM  `leads` WHERE `status` =  'Passed' 
    and`campaign_id` =  '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f046bd1d8ee' AND `datesubmitted_c` >= Date_Add(curDate(), INTERVAL -65 YEARS)

Comment: Also, could you do a `DESC leads;`? I wonder if datesubmitted_c isn't of type date/time

Comment: datesubmitted_c is standard mm/dd/yyyy , I have other date fields I can utilize that have the same but also post hh:mm am/pm as well.

Comment: That's you're problem.  If its mm/dd/yyyy, those aren't dates.  You'll need to parse the date STR_TO_DATE(datesubmitted_c, '%m/%d/%y') AS date  to turn it into a field of the date/time type

Comment: A standard date time field would look like 21-Dec-2012

Comment: AND STR_TO_DATE(datesubmitted_c, '%m/%d/%y') >= Date_Add(curDate(), INTERVAL -65 YEARS) would this be correct?

Comment: yes............  P.S.  I'd love to know if this was the problem :)  If it is, an upvote and accept would be greatly appreciated :)